# Density of absolutely continuous measures on a Polish Space

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Consider the set of all probability measures on a Polish space $X$ (equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{B}(X)$). I am wondering if there exist conditions under which a subset of measures that are abolutely continuous w.r.t. a given (fixed) measure, say $\mu$, is dense (w.r.t. the weak topology). When $X=\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mu$ is atomless, this follows from the convolution argument.

Comment: I think this works if and only if $\mu$ has topological support equal to all of $X$.

Comment: @d.k.o. Well, the usual proof just works in that case, no?

Comment: @MartinHairer What do you mean exactly by the usual proof?

Comment: @d.k.o. I meant the proof that every measure can be approximated by an atomic measure supported on some fixed countable dense set. Just replace the atoms by the restriction of $\mu$ to small balls, see for example the construction at the bottom of p.16 of my SPDE notes: https://www.hairer.org/notes/SPDEs_Course.pdf.

Comment: @d.k.o. You're right, thanks!